# how iPhone 5 apps will work on older iPhones?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-4, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

how iPhone 5 apps will work on older iPhones?

For example, if I create an app to take advantage of the 4 inch screen will I also have to create another version of my app to support the older 3.5 inch screen?

**PS**

Im doing it **programmatically**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution

Comment: You can use:

    #define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

then use a simple `if` statement :


        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {

        // What ever changes
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable Autolayout in the interface builder, it will support both screen sizes for the iPhone.
If doing it programmatically, there's this question that asked something similar. 
[Implementing auto layout for views generated programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593153/implementing-auto-layout-for-views-generated-programmatically)

Comment: Follow Simon's advice in the documentation it handles programmatically

Answer (score 2):

Apple added something called AutoLayout. They added this to iOS (and OSX) SDKs to counter the screen resolution differences by allowing you to set constraints to your view elements.

[Here's the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html)

To use it programmatically, you can define constraints using [NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html)

Comment: do you know a good example for : NSLayoutConstraint

Comment: Good question. Most of the tutorials I found deal with Interface Builder.

Comment: See @CBredlow link on his edited response. That's how you use it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Auto Layout concept, It will work,

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2