# Custom splitted cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, uilabel, swift2

I am trying to create custom splitted cell:

[my custom splitted cell](http://postimg.org/image/wsx76qjtb/)

that contains 2 UILabels at top and 2 custom UITextFields at bottom.

And I want programmatically configure the ratio of left and right part of cell. It should be sometimes 1:1 and sometimes 3:1.

I tried `override func layoutSubviews()` in my SplittedCellController: UITabelViewCell

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    print("cell layout called")
    let leftPart = 2
    let rightPart = 1
    let spacing: CGFloat = 17.0
    let width = self.frame.width
    let allParts = leftPart + rightPart
    let leftPartWidth = (width / CGFloat(allParts)) * CGFloat(leftPart)
    let rightPartWidth = (width / CGFloat(allParts)) * CGFloat(rightPart)

    print(leftPartWidth)
    print(rightPartWidth)


    let leftLabelFrame = leftLabel.frame
    let leftTFFrame = leftTextField.frame
    leftLabel.frame = CGRectMake(leftLabelFrame.origin.x, leftLabelFrame.origin.y, leftPartWidth, leftLabelFrame.size.height)
    leftTextField.frame = CGRectMake(leftTFFrame.origin.x, leftTFFrame.origin.y, leftPartWidth, leftTFFrame.size.height)

    let rightLabelFrame = rightLabel.frame
    let rightTFFrame = rightTextField.frame
    rightLabel.frame = CGRectMake(leftLabelFrame.origin.x + leftPartWidth + spacing, rightLabelFrame.origin.y, rightPartWidth, rightLabelFrame.size.height)

    rightTextField.frame = CGRectMake(leftTFFrame.origin.x + leftPartWidth + spacing, rightTFFrame.origin.y, rightPartWidth, rightTFFrame.size.height)

}
```

But it hasn't desired effect:
[actual effect](http://postimg.org/image/3whpd10tl/)

In first section the cell seams to be ok, but when I tapped on a textfield - , desired change disappears and moreover in the second section the cells are not affected.

And when I tap on "changed" cell, the right bottom textfield shows in rightView additional label, that should happen only in section 2 -"http: //postimg.org/image/8lctbl1ad/" after "Another cell"

Here is the code I use for displaying rightview in textField:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    if rightAdditionalLabelShown {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        label.text = textInRightAdditionalLabel
        label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        label.textAlignment = .Right
        rightView = label
        rightViewMode = .Always
    }


    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(0.5)

    border.name = "borderLayer"
    border.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

My question is how should I configure the cell to fit desired ratio and what can I do about that rightView?

Comment: The solution was simpler than I thought. [Max MacLeod's answer was very helpful][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707229/how-to-change-label-constraints-during-runtime/19707579#19707579