# Th orientation for device disappearing data on table view that put on scroll view - IOS

Tags: ios, tableview, scrollview, swift5

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVkZy.png) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMbde.jpg)  I have a screen contains table view and segment control that has 3 indexes every index call an api that return array of movies . I displayed the movies on table view and put all the components of the screen in scroll view and set its constraint very well .And i ran my app and it worked well.
the problem caused when i make rotation for my device the data in table view disappeared
if any one can help me ?

i created a variable from height of table view constraint to change it based on the array of movies  that come from api .
I tried to change the height of scroll view and its content and used ViewDidLayoutViews() function to update the height but the problem still .

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        scrollviewhight.constant = movieListTableView.contentSize.height
    }
```

Comment: table view has its own scroll view you dont need to separate scrollview, can you share your view as a pic

Comment: my view contain[view of view controller - scroll view - content View- [search bar -segment control -table view]].

Comment: I added two picture above . And i used scroll view to make the user seeing  the content of screen easily when he rotate the device .

Comment: you can have just the tableview, but it depends on your UX, (to me you shouldn't use 2 scroll view (scrollview , tableview) in one gesture )

Comment: maybe this link helps you: https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView

Comment: if you want to use scrollview check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37223709/using-scroll-view-with-autolayout-swift